# Java - how to get an element from Arraylist and insert into another Array?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm very confusing at this point. 
I'm making a cards game and do not know how to write the "deal" method. The "deal" method deals a certain number of cards to each player in Player array. 
My deck class contains an ArrayList as this:

```
public ArrayList<WarCard> cardStack = new ArrayList<WarCard>();
```

and I have added 52 pre-made cards to cardStack. 
My player array has two elements, player 1 and player 2...
My question is, **how do I assign the 52 cards from cardStack to player 1 or player 2?** I have no idea of where to start...
this is what I have so far:

```
public void deal(WarPlayer[] players, int numberOfCards){
    //whats the "certain number"? - suppose each one gets 26 cards - 1/2 of     the total cards
    numberOfCards=26;//26 cards go to each player
    for(int i=0;i<26;i++){
    players[i]=cardStack.get(i);
    }

}
```

and this block of code does not work...as expected.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you know what `players[i]` does, what `=` does and what `cardStack.get(i)` does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your can code something like this:

```
    // let's say you have a cardStack containing 52 cards
    ArrayList<String> cardStack = new ArrayList<String>();

    //you can shuffle the cards before dealing
    shuffle(cardStack);

    String[] players = new String[]{"player1", "player2"};

    //this is the loop to deal cards to all players in the array
    for (int i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {

        // if you need to deal 10 cards to each player
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            players[i].addCard(cardStack.get(0));   // assuming your Player Object has an addCard method

            // you will need to remove the card from the cardStack since you gave it to the player
            cardStack.remove(0);                    
        }

    }
```

After dealing (for this example) 10 cards to each player, the list will be left with 32 cards and each player will have a `List` of 10 cards.

Hope this helps

EDIT:
Edited `player[i].addCard(cardStack.get(j));`  to make sure that the player gets the first card on the deck. It should be:

```
player[i].addCard(cardStack.get(0));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have a "hand" method which may be equivalent to "addCard" method.